# Why is the product of the roots of $p(z) = 1 + z + az^n$ equal to $1$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

This should be very straightforward to show, but I am having some issues doing so. We have:

$$1 + z + az^n = a(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\dots(z-z_n),$$

where $z_1$, $z_2$, $\dots , z_n$ are the roots of $p$. Clearly,

$$1 = (-1)^na(z_1 z_2\dots z_n).$$

I'm pretty much stuck at this point - it seems like the absolute value of the product of the roots will be $1/a$, but this isn't what we want.

I suppose that the problem statement could be wrong - I am working out of the Berkeley book of problems and solutions in mathematics, and this is part of an answer to a problem. But, I'm checking in to be sure.

Comment: The statement is wrong; you are correct. Of course, you must assume $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Your product is $\pm \frac 1a$ according to the degree $n$ be even or odd respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$1+z+2z^2
$.

The roots are
$\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-8}}{4}
=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-7}}{4}
$
and their product is
$\frac{-1+\sqrt{-7}}{4}\frac{-1-\sqrt{-7}}{4}
=\frac{1-(-7)}{16}
=\frac12
$
which is not $1$.

Comment: Multiply by $a$?

Comment: That is the way - multiply by $a$ and all is OK.

Comment: Thank you - I thought it seemed strange, and I appreciate the counterexample, helps me see why it doesn't work. Note to self: don't trust answers given in the back of the book! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Vieta's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

If you don't want to use Vieta's theorem, you can also expand the brackets to get this result.

$a$ has to be non-zero.

Comment: Doesn't Vieta's theorem require $a$ to be $1$, or at least $|a|=1$ ?

Comment: @Peter You can always divide by $a$.

Comment: But then, the constant is $\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: @Peter I think the constants are on the other side of the roots.

Comment: Thanks for the theorem link - that will help me a lot if I run into similar problems.